# How to make special effects between two brackets?

Tags: css

I want to add color to sentences between brackets like '(' sentence..... ')'
I think css can do this, but if css can't do this can any one tell me how to do by JavaScript?

An example of what I want to do:

### HTML

```
This is Paragraph (I want to change text color between brackets) bla bla bla...
```

### CSS

```
Selector to select between '(' and ')' { color: #ccc111; }
```

Thanks & sorry for my bad English!

Comment: Can't you use a `span` with a special class and style it accordingly?

Comment: CSS can't detect the content in an element.

Comment: css isn't intended to find and style text. It'd be FAR easier to just wrap the stuff inside the brackets with a couple span tags. `foo (<span style="woohoo">asdfasdfasdfasdf</span>) bar`

Answer (score 0):

There are about a gazillion ways to select it. The most common is using a span, here is example:

```
<div>
This is Paragraph <span>(I want to change text color between brackets)</span> bla bla bla...
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze86e/).

```
#some_content span{
    color: red;
}
```

here I selected all spans inside the object with `id='some_content'`.

as an alternative you can use for example `p>span{` to select all spans as direct child element inside a `<p>` or you can make `<span class='colorful_text'>` and then select it with `.colorful_text{`. In short, read the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) on css selectors for more options to accommodate your need.

EDIT:

If `<span>` is too much, you can use something generic that doesn't exist, like the way I used `<m>` in the example bellow.

```
m{
    color: #ccc111;
}
```

with this all the text inside the `m`'s turns yellowish.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ze86e/2/).

Comment: I have WordPress blog, and I have a lot of post, so I can't put span for every brackets, I need way to apply the effect to all the brackets, doesn't difference (JavaScript or CSS)

Comment: @Baselart, you have to surround them with something to apply the different color. Even if it's 1 letter, for example with </m>.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="para">This is Paragraph (<span>I want to change text color between brackets</span>) bla bla bla...</div>
```

CSS

```
.para span {
    color:#f00;  /* what ever colur you want */  
}
```